# c++: declare template as a class member

Tags: c++, class, templates

i want a `node` class to build a tree. `node` is a template class with template arguements `_Data` and `_Container`. For no recursion in template arguements, i let `_Container` be a template class instand of a class. i declare `typedef _Data data_type` in `node`, and want to use `node::container_type` like `node::data_type`. How can i do?

```
template<
    typename
        _Data,
    template<typename T> class
        _Container = std::vector>
struct node
{
    typedef _Data data_type;

    //TODO container_type

    typedef node<_Data, _Container> type;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<type> ptr;
    typedef _Container<ptr> ptrs;
    Data data;
    ptrs children;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, you may use something like the following:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Container>
struct node
{
    using data_type = T;

    template <typename U>
    using container_templ = Container<U>;

};
```

Note that `container_templ` is not a type (whereas `container_templ<T>` is).

Note also that `std::vector` doesn't match template `Container` as `std::vector` takes an extra (default) parameter `Allocator`, so you have to do something like:

```
template <typename T>
using My_Vector = std::vector<T>;
template<typename T, template<typename> class Container = My_Vector>
struct node;
```